# Usando $tempo = date("d/m/Y H:i:s",time()-86400); para deletar agendamentos passado

Tags: php, html

Estou usando este código para excluir os agendamentos com datas e horários já passados em relação ao tempo atual.

```
<?php
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($select_agenda)){

$id = $res['id'];
$nome = $res['nome'];
$tel = $res['tel'];
$cel = $res['cel'];
$email = $res['email'];
$plano = $res['plano'];
$data = $res['data'];
$horas = $res['horas'];
$tempo = date("d/m/Y  H:i:s",time()-86400);

$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM agendar WHERE data < '$tempo'");
?>
```

Sabendo que 86400 refere-se a quantidade de segundos de um dia, estou usando o código acima, e excluindo os agendamentos passados referente ao tempo atual, na virada das datas.

Seguindo este raciocínio, alterei para -1800, para que fosse excluídos os arquivos a cada 30 minutos. Ficando assim:

```
$tempo = date("d/m/Y  H:i:s",time()-1800);
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM agendar WHERE data < '$tempo'");
```

Mas dessa forma esta excluindo todos os registros, e não o ultimo 30 minutos referente ao tempo real.

Os agendamentos são feitos com intervalos de 30 minutos.

Se os amigos puderem me dar uma ajudar de como devo proceder para os agendamentos sejam excluídos a cada 30 minutos, ficarei muito agradecido.

Grande abraço à todos.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi bem a pergunta, mas é possível excluir os registros com um campo tipo "datetime" com valores inferiores a 30 minutos do tempo atual utilizando na query de exclusão a [função NOW() do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now):

```
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM agendar WHERE data <  NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE");
```

Lembrando que `NOW()` retorna a data/hora atual, e com o `INTERVAL` pode adicionar (usando `+`) ou subtrair (usando `-`) do tempo atual (ou seja, do valor retornado por `NOW()`).

Onde utilizei `MINUTE`, é possível substituir por: `YEAR` para ano,  `MONTH` para mês, `DAY` para dia, `HOUR` para hora, `MINUTE` para minuto, `SECOND` para segundo.

OBS: vale lembrar que a LIB mysql está [depreciada para versões a partir do PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) , utilize [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) ou [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php).

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Olá Allan, muito obrigado pela sua atenção ao meu problema. Mas estou usando um DatePicker onde seleciono a data e gravo em uma coluna Varchar e não em DateTime, e um Select onde seleciono os horários e gravo em uma coluna tambem em Varchar, tem como você me mostrar como alterar o meu código para funcionar com a sua dica? Abraços.

Comment: Você poderia concatenar o valor do DatePicker e do Select para montar um campo do tipo datetime e gravar em um campo adequado. Seria muito prático para utilizar a data como objeto, também para ordenação com filtros como > maior ou < menor. O que acha?

Answer (score 1):

Para subtrair 30 minutos do seu tempo inicial em PHP, ao invés de `$tempo = date("d/m/Y  H:i:s",time()-1800);` você pode fazer:

```
$tempoInicial = date("d/m/Y  H:i:s",time());
$menosTrintaMinutos = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-30 minutes", strtotime($tempoInicial )));

//echo 'tempo inicial: '.$tempoInicial.'<br/>';
//echo 'tempo -30m: '.$menosTrintaMinutos;

$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM agendar WHERE data < '$menosTrintaMinutos '");
```

Executando `$sql` você deleta todos os registros da tabela `agendar` onde há mais de 30 minutos passados (quando a coluna `data` é inferior à data atual descontando-se 30 minutos).

Comment: Isso na verdade tem pouco a ver resposta e não responde. Parece que você não leu a questão. No SOen isso seria sinalizado para remoção.

Comment: @felipsmartins, eu fiz questão de editar minha resposta para ser mais claro. Anteriormente eu só havia mostrado um caminho, resolvi completar o código para ser mais específico. Parece que você não leu minha resposta (:

Comment: Olá feresjorge, gostaria de agradecer pela sua atenção, mas eu substitui as linhas **`$tempo = date("d/m/Y  H:i:s",time()-1800);` e `$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM agendar WHERE data < '$tempo'");`** pelas  **`$tempoInicial = date("d/m/Y  H:i:s",time());`** , **`$menosTrintaMinutos = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-30 minutes", strtotime($tempoInicial)));`** e o sql para **`$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM agendar WHERE data < '$menosTrintaMinutos'");`**, mas continua excluindo todos os registros. Tem ideia de onde estou errando? Abraços.